# Finite Number of Zeros in Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be a non-trivial solution of $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+ q(x) y = 0$$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$ where $q(x)$ is a positive function. Then prove that $y(x)$ has at most a finite number of zeros in $[a,b]$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $y$ has an infinite number of zeros on $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, the set of zeros has an accumulation point $x_0\in[a,b]$. Then $y(x_0)=y'(x_0)=0$. By uniqueness of solution, $y(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Julián. But then what is the significance of q(x) being a positive function?

Comment: It has no significance; the result is independent of the sign of $q$. The sign of $q$ is important in oscillation theory, where you usually try to prove that there are zeros.

Comment: Why in accumulation point we have $y'(x_0)=0$?.